# Hide android app under development

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-games

It is written in the [google play games services guides](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub#enabling_accounts_for_testing) that we can hide apps under development in Google+. The given steps are :

- Go to https://plus.google.com and sign in with the Google+ account you are using to test the game.
- Select the account's profile by moving your cursor over the Home icon and then select Profile from the panel that slides in.
- Click About at the top.
- Find the section that says Apps and click the Edit link at the bottom.
- Uncheck Show apps card on your Google+ profile and click Save.

My issue is that I do not see any 'profile" button, the interface may have changed. If I go to "my account" it says "Control, protect, and secure your account, all in one place", but I don't see any "about" or "apps" or "uncheck show apps card" button.

I guess I should find the "Show apps card on your Google+ profile" checkbox in "Sign-in & security", but I don't see it.
Do you know how I should do it ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The only issue that I can see with this is the Google + account that you are using.

It is stated in [this](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub#hiding_apps_under_development) that you need to sign in with the Google+ account you are using to test the game. So make sure that you enable this account for the testing.

So for the short answer, first, you need to [enable the account](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub#enabling_accounts_for_testing) for the testing then 
check this [Giving testing access to alpha and beta users](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub#giving_testing_access_to_alpha_and_beta_users) before you can hide the application.

> *Note:* Remember to add yourself as a tester, or the Play Games SDK will not work for your user account in enabling the account for
>   testing